# error using textread in loop

Tags: matlab

i have the following code,in which i am trying to find all data.m files and delete string that matches expr.

```
fileData = dir();  
m_file_idx = 1;     
filenames = {fileData.name};  
index = regexp(filenames,'\w*_data.m\w*','match') ;
inFiles = filenames(~cellfun(@isempty,index));    
i=1;
for idx = i : length(inFiles)        
    data_m_files=inFiles{i}; 
    disp(data_m_files)
    C = textread('data_m_files', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
    expr ='\.DataType[ =]+''auto''';  
 C = C(cellfun(@isempty, regexp(C, expr)));
    i=i+1;
end
```

my output is:

```
this_is_data.m

Error using textread (line 167)
File not found.
```

if i use the same code by manually entering the data_m_file name,textread works fine and i get the desired result.but when i try to put in the loop,it gives me error.am i using textread incorrectly?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're using `textread` incorrectly.

The first argument of `textread` must be a string containing the file name. You have specified it to be `'data_m_files'`, so MATLAB looks for a file named "data_m_files", which obviously does not exist.

You should pass the value of `data_m_files`, so remove the quotes from `'data_m_files'`, like so:

```
C = textread(data_m_files, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
```

and this should work.